# PyMongo - name 'SON' is not defined

Tags: python, mongodb

While learning MongoDB in Python with PyMongo package, I have an error when following "getting started" guide from MongoDB website [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/getting-started/).

Here is the code I have issue with

```
cursor = db.inventory.find({"size": SON([("h", 14), ("w", 21), ("uom", "cm")])})
```

and here is the error message I get:

> NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
> 1 cursor = db.inventory.find(
> 2     {"size": SON([("h", 14), ("w", 21), ("uom", "cm")])})

> NameError: name 'SON' is not defined

I have successfully executed all pieces from start till this line and even I can run the code afterwards, but not this specific query.

After a bit of Googling, I found [this](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/son.html) Post which explains SON but does not narrow down to troubleshooting.

In case these info would help, I am running these code on Mac OS 10.13, Anaconda 1.8.1, with Jupyter. I tested on both Python 2.7 and 3.6 to ensure nothing is wrong with Python libraries. All relevant packages asked by tutorial are installed via Jupyter

Comment: Are you trying to find documents where the key `size` has the values defined in the SON Object?

Comment: I am following tutorial materials only. I believe, the code is trying to find items by looking at multiple criteria likr "h", "w", and "uom".

Answer (score 0):

Use bson.son.SON instead of just SON

so full working example is:

`cursor = db.inventory.find({"size": bson.son.SON([("h", 14), ("w", 21), ("uom", "cm")])})`

In other words it was/is a namespace problem not adequately explained in MongoDB documentation.